# Why does matplotlib bar3d plot auto reverse x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I'm trying to plot a 3D bar chart using matplotlib library.

The problem is that whatever I try my x-axis ends up to be automatically inverted (i.e. values goes from biggest to smallest) while y and z axis are as expected.

I'll explain the problem with this simple tutorial I found online (https://pythonprogramming.net/3d-bar-charts-python-matplotlib/).

Here is the code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

xpos = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
ypos = [2,3,4,5,1,6,2,1,7,2]
num_elements = len(xpos)
zpos = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
dx = np.ones(10)
dy = np.ones(10)
dz = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

ax1.bar3d(xpos, ypos, zpos, dx, dy, dz, color='#00ceaa')
plt.show()
```

I'm supposed to obtain this figure
[Figure from tutorial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBiKe.png)

While I'm obtaining this figure
[My figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhWDz.png)

As you can see the x-axis is inverted.

Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Yeah, but that was presumably a bug, which is fixed now. What you obtain is actually correct (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule).

Comment: Yes you are right, that tutorial totally tricked me. Dumb question. The thing is that I feel more comfortable with the first picture's style of displaying axes, but ok, the "new" way makes sense as well. Thanks for the explanation!